# Filter various text at the same time in r

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a datafrme like this:

```
v1 v2 v3
2  4  hello
3  1  hello
4  5  hi
7  8  hi
6  0  greetings
8  0  greetings
9  7  hola
```

I need to filter from v3, hello, greetings and hola. I tried this:

```
x = filter(data$v3, c("hello","greetings","hola"))
```

but does not work, my original data is a very extensive dataframe with 110000 rows and 86 colums. I need to filter more than three. The dataframe I looking for is like:

```
v1 v2 v3
2  4  hello
3  1  hello
6  0  greetings
8  0  greetings
9  7  hola
```

Thank´s for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[`filter`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/filter) requires as second argument;

> Logical predicates defined in terms of the variables in .data.
>   Multiple conditions are combined with &. Only rows where the condition
>   evaluates to TRUE are kept.

So we have to pass statements that return `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each row. You could use the `%in%` operator, for example as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(v3 %in% c("hello","greetings","hola"))
```

which returns

```
  v1 v2        v3
1  2  4     hello
2  3  1     hello
3  6  0 greetings
4  8  0 greetings
5  9  7      hola
```

Hope this helps.